# Distribute client app update to app store without the certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I've done an app update for a client.

He previously work with another external dev, and have no access to the certificate private key.

Using xCode, (as team member), looks like a can get the client provisioning profile, but not the Distribution certificate.

What are the solution, Are the client have to create a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, revoke and create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to build an app for the app store without the certificate. As @Shubhank says, you'll have to revoke the certificate and create a new one.

Comment: I can create one as team member and link to provisioning to it?
Will the client have access to this new one, or should I provide it manually(as a backup(?

Comment: If you are an admin you can create a new cert. You should then export it in the keychain and mail the .p12 file to your client.